# BigQuery cannot find existing table in location

Tags: google-bigquery

getting following error

> "Not found: Table bigquery-public-data:stackoverflow.post_questions
> was not found in location US" while trying to query a public Google
> Bigquery dataset"

here is the query :

```
select split(tags,'|'), count(*) from `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.post_questions`
where extract (year from creation_date) >= 2008
group by tags
```

The dataset is located in the US so im confused, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `s`: `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` instead of `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.post_questions`